# Removing extra comma from a java string array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of type string, I want to remove the extra comma from string, if it exists

```
String[] myList= new String[]{"hello","Mr","How","are","You",};
```

How to remove this extra comma from this string array?

Comment: Uh - hit the "delete" key?

Comment: That comma doesn't do anything.  The compiler ignores it.  What's the issue, exactly?

Comment: @DavidWallace have you noticed the last , ?

Comment: Yes, I noticed the last comma.  I didn't think it would compile, but I copied and pasted it into my IDE.  It compiles and runs fine.  I used a debugger to check the value of the array, and it's just as if the extra comma weren't there.  @KickButtowski

Comment: @DavidWallace it seems compilers are so smarter that they used to be? lol

Comment: Actually i am going to convert this string  into a JSON format and send to other system using webservices.

Comment: @user7396 doesn't matter what you are going to do: if the compiler accept it, the structure in memory will be the same with trailing comma or not.

Answer (score 1):

The trialing comma is ignored, see the [JLS - 10.6. Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer is written as a comma-separated list of expressions, enclosed by braces `{` and `}`.
>
> A trailing comma may appear after the last expression in an array initializer and is *ignored*.

It's useful when you want to initialize long list (some people find it more readable):

```
String[] myList = {
                   "hello",
                   "Mr",
                   "How",
                   "are",
                   "You",
                   "I'm",
                   "fine",
                   "thank",
                   "you",
                  };
```

You have no way to remove it programmatically unless you iterate on the source file.

Comment: I read somewhere that this behavior is accepted to make easyer code generation, poors generator can generate array initializers without caring about comma placements.